# Why $\,\mathrm d(\sin x)\,$ is valid as differential of the integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let's say we have
$$\int\sin^3\!x\,\mathrm dx=\int\sin x\left(1-\cos^2\!x\right)\mathrm dx=\\[3pt]=-\int\left(1-\cos^2\!x\right)\mathrm d(\cos x)=-\cos x+\frac{1}{3}\cos^3\!x+c\;.$$

Why is $\,\mathrm d(\cos x)\,$ valid if that is not the base of the Riemann rectangles ?

Comment: I know where that differential comes from but why the integral still works?

Comment: I think that should be $d(\cos(x))$. The reason is that it is a notational trick of chain rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integration works because the change of variables rescales the $x$ axis in a nonuniform way. If you write this calculation for a definite integral (with limits that change when you make the change of variables) you can see how the uniform width area approximating rectangles in the original integral become variable width but still approximating rectangles after the change.

Sorry I don't  have the time to draw the picture. Perhaps someone else here will   edit the question to include one.